# Including <string> in c++ using Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans

Netbeans fails compilation on:

```
#include <string>
```

Output says:

```
main.c:10:18: fatal error: string: No such file or directory
 #include <string>
```

The previous two declarations are included fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

I have removed all the code afterwards to make sure.

I am using cygwin_64 and it installed as per Netbeans c++ installation manual and shows versions in CLI

I am new to C++ and I know there have been similar questions, but the answers didn't help me.

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling c++ code and not plain c?

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ, you're most probably right. main file has .c extension, not .cpp or .cxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to create new project and follow these steps:

1. Click `File->Create project`.
2. Choose `C/C++`, then `C/C++ application`, click `Next`.
3. Enter project name and in the right choose `C++` in combobox. Or `C++11`.